# how can I take average of this column in python?

Tags: csv, file

I tried to go take average of this column but could not. can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: You need to make sure that all the values in the column are of numeric type. You have an error because of some row containing strings.

Comment: thank you for the answer Saloua. how can I do it? from the excel document?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not add your code and/or data as image, but copy them into the post instead (see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details).

Comment: i am new here, thanks for advice, I will do it in my next question :-)

Comment: @EdipMusaogullari I added an answer to your question

Comment: I saw it, I will apply it when I have time. how can I give you reputation? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the data type for your column is numeric or not.

For average function, you need to have numeric data, should not be the string.

Comment: This hank you Saloua :-)

Comment: You can change the data type of column by from Number Section of Home tab in excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the column values type using `dtypes`
Here is an example `DataFrame` and how to get the column values type

```
    Data = {'Products': ['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE'],
           'Prices': ['200','700','400','1200','900']}
 
    df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
    print (df['Products'].dtypes)
    print (df['Price'].dtypes)
```

Here you can see that the values in the column Price are `int64`
Now if I add a new row with a string value the column values type will be different `object`

```
 df.loc[len(df)] = ["Some product", "222"]
 print (df['Price'].dtypes)
```

Which means in your case that you have some inconsistency in data values types in the column you are using. You need to find the rows causing that and see if you can fix pre-process them by for example simply enforcing the column values type to be `numeric`.

```
df['Prices'] = df['Prices'].astype(int)
print (df['Prices'].dtypes)
```